# Are frame challenges allowed on this site?

Tags: discussion

I did a meta search (of course skipping the help section, duh) for "frame challenge" and did not find any direct answer. There was only a post about not meeting the "justified frame challenge" criteria, which was not elaborated on.

On Parenting, a site on which I was formerly a mod, frame challenges are not allowed unless they also answer the question in a helpful way.

[This question](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/15340/3246) has a very helpful but slightly frame challenging [answer](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/15342/3246) (which I upvoted, because it's well supported and completely correct), but the OP recognized it as "not an answer." The problem is that there is no non-frame-challenging answer because the problem is not what the OP imagines it might be, so asking for a specific answer will only address symptoms of cyanide poisoning, which the answer provided.

Which leads to the question asked. Thank you. (Now I'll go read the help section.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say - considering the broader context it ought to be fine.

We're trying to solve OP's problem, not their assumptions. "Its not cynide poisoning *because*..." solves the problem halfway.

> Basically, I can find general lists of symptoms, but I'm interested in how it played out in specific cases.

OP wants *specific* cases of it happening, which is a bit tricky, since you literally need to find someone who has had a dog with apple-seed induced cynide poisoning, or a suspected case of that ruled out by a vet.

If it was a 'new' question, I'd have suggested say, soft tissue damage (our late Mr Ash had a lifelong limp, but nothing obvious in the X rays) - which would be a frame challenge too.

There's nothing wrong with challenging an assumption in a question assuming you back it up appropriately.

Comment: Thank you. This is a bit different than I'm accustomed to, but likely more helpful to the OP.